# How to have a response image grid with div?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

i am very New with html/css , i to learn how can I create a responsive image grid with div .
My Codec:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>My Website</title>
<style>

.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: 40vh 30vh 30vh;
grid-gap: 10px;

}   
.header > img {

grid-column: 1/ span 4;
grid-row: 1 / span 6;   
}

</style>    
</head> 
<body>

<div class="container">
     <div class="header">
        <img src="/home/image/my_2.png" />
     </div>



</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I don't know how an image siting to header , can please anyone help , how to do it , Thanks!

Comment: Provide more details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! , i am very new with html/css ... .I will a image to my header landing , but i don't how to do it...

Comment: @3edf1w Welcome. Check out [mcve] for info on how much code we need in order to be able to help you! Specifically we would need the code in the question as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the route of the image if is good? This means if

```
<img src="/home/image/my_2.png" />
```

Points and show your image.

If his is correct, for yor image to have a responsive size, you need to set the styles as this:

```
<img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" src="/home/image/my_2.png" />
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Veryyyyy Thanks ! , you have right ! , i think my problem was the route.. with :                                                                                                              <img style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;"  src="/home/me/Document/HTML/work/my2.png"  alt="header" class="topt" />    . Now can i see the image to my head !! , Thanks !